# ANTLR4 custom tokens

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am using `C#` version for generating `ANTLR4` files. I have used custom tokens by using this option `TokenLabelType=Token`. Everything is fine but `c#` compiler gives error in `MAtch(..)` and `input(...)` because this does not type cast to my custom tokens. Whereas ANTLR3 gives the proper casting for this functions. I am extending my own token from this class `Antlr4.Runtime.CommonToken`.

C# compiler throws this error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Antlr4.Runtime.IToken' to 'Grammar.ActionParser.Token'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".
```

Please tell how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your custom token class named 'Token'?  If so, check the using statements to make sure that the parser is not confusing the Antlr4.Runtime.Token class for your token class. If not, change it to the actual type of your custom token class.

Comment: I have changed Token to "MyToken". But still I am getting the same error. While generating the files,ANTLR4 has to typecast it to the custom token in the following line "((MulOPerationContext)_localctx).op = _input.Lt(1);". Whereas ANTLR3 typecasts this to the custom Token so I didnot face any error while using ANTLR3. Please tell what is missed from our side for ANTLR4.

Comment: Same error meaning that it is 'exactly' the same error?  In any case, the cast of a token to a context is suspect.  Will need to see your grammar to help further.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.Please find my grammar.
options 
{
    TokenLabelType=MyToken;
}
statement : expression EOF;
expression returns[object obj]
 :expression op=(MULT | DIV) expression #MulOPeration
 |INT                                  #IntOperation
 ;
INT : [0-9]+; 
MULT :'*';
DIV : '/';
Apart from this rules, I have overriden Emit() EmitEOF() and NextToken() functions.
The command which I am using to execute this is 
<Exec Command="java -jar antlr4-csharp-4.4.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar Printing.g4 -package Genfiles -visitor -o Genfiles -Dlanguage=CSharp_v4_5&#xD;&#xA;"/>Plz help.Thanks

Comment: Please find MyToken Class definition
public class MyToken : CommonToken
    {
        int refId;
        public int RefId
        {
            get { return refId; }
            set { refId = value; }
        }
        
        public MyToken(Tuple<ITokenSource, ICharStream> input, int type, int channel,
                       int start, int stop)
            : base(input,type,channel,start,stop)
        {
           
        }

        public MyToken(int type, string text)
            : base(type, text)
        {
            
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same issue in ANTLR4.7 with C++ target. All the labels on tokens in contexts properly use my custom token class, however the code that assigns those labels is not ready for that, trying to assign base `Token *` to `MyToken *`. I've used workaround for this issue by declaring

```
virtual MyToken *match(size_t ttype) override;
virtual MyToken *matchWildcard() override;
virtual MyToken *getCurrentToken() override;
virtual MyToken *consume() override;
```

in generated parser. All these overrides do is call base version of themselves and `static_cast<MyToken *>` on result of that call. I assume something similar should be possible in C#.

The proper way would probably require fixing appropriate .stg file (under /org/antlr/v4/tool/templates/codegen/<target language> inside antlr .jar file - there is also a way of overriding it without the need to edit original .jar) so the generated code for label assignments does these casts without the need to override return type (or to make it generate the above routines automatically).